# Rearrange text using Find/Replace in Atom

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have a piece of code in Atom that looks like this:

```
replace party ="0001" "FEDERALIST"                                           
replace party ="0008" "ANTI-DEMOCRAT"                                        
replace party ="0009" "JEFFERSON REPUBLICAN"
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
replace party ="FEDERALIST" "0001"                                            
replace party ="ANTI-DEMOCRAT" "0008"                                         
replace party ="JEFFERSON REPUBLICAN" "0009"
```

I know I can use regular expressions to find the relevant pieces of text, but I was not able to find a way to rearrange the order of the code within each line. I was wondering if something like finding `"[\d]{4}"` and replacing it with `\"[A-Z- ]+\"` is possible.

Comment: Try replacing `("\d{4}") ("[^"]*") *$` with `$2 $1`. See https://regex101.com/r/OnFrr7/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's amazing, it works. If you write it, I'll choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*:     `("\d{4}") ("[^"]*") *$`
*Replace With*: `$2 $1`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnFrr7/1).

**Details**

- `("\d{4}")` - Capturing group 1: `"`, 4 digits and `"`
- - a space
- `("[^"]*")` - Capturing group 2: `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then `"`
- `*` - 0+ spaces
- `$` - end of line.